# How to check if a custom (pseudo) selector has been added to jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, browser-feature-detection

I grabbed the following snippet from the comments on [this post at CSSTricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/).

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "containsNC": function(elem, i, match, array) {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    }
});
```

Essentially, it provides a pseudo-selector `:containsNC`, which works just like [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) but is case-insensitive.

I want be able to detect if this selector is available so I can conditionally use `:contains` as a fallback.

**How can I check for the presence of such a custom selector?**

Alternatively, is there a better way to do the case insensitive matching in newer jQuery?

For reference, here's how I'm currently using `:contains` (*to filter a list of Facebook friends*)

```
$('#friend-search').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    var $search = $(this).val(),
        $friends = $('.friend'),
        match = ':contains(' + $search + ')';
    $friends.hide().filter(match).show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After posting this question, I did some poking around, and found the response quite easily:

```
var containsNC_isDefined = typeof $.expr[":"].containsNC === "function";
if (containsNC_isDefined) alert(":containsNC exists!");
```